# System losing energy in a cold room

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

A system (eg. below), that constanty loses energy (ie. as heat due to friction) is kept in a cold room, will it lose energy faster compared the same system in a warmer/room temperature environment?

***Hint: Cold air absorbs heat faster***

Example of system:

---

> A Non Accelerated Disc rotating initially with some velocity
>   constantly rubs against its axis with some friction (which 
>   reduces its speed).***

Comment: What gives you the idea that the character limit is 150? This is not twitter or equivalent. Mind you for some who post it would be a **very** good limit...

Answer (score 0):

You haven't put your question very clearly, but you seem to have answered it yourself. Yes, a heated object will lose heat more quickly in a very cold room than one at normal room temperature (15 C). This probably won't reduce the friction unless your axle contracts more than the disc, which might happen if they were made of different materials.